# Async / await in node nested functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to get `async / await` to trigger events in order, but it seems I'm missing something as my console.log markers are triggering in reverse to the order I was hoping for.

I 'm wondering if is to do with my use of nested functions in `users.js` but having tried multiple variations of `async / await`, it consistently doesn't work as expected.

// index.js

```
var users = require("./users.js"); 

app.post("/getToken", async function(req, res) {  
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const user = await users(email, password) 
        // running this should output console.log("No 1") 
        // from users.js first, but doesn't ?

        console.log('No 2')
        if (user) {
            var payload = {
                id: user.id
            };
            var token = jwt.encode(payload, cfg.jwtSecret);
            res.json({
                token: token
            });
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
});
```

// users.js

```
module.exports = function(emailAddress, password) {
    db.connect();
    var query = `
        SELECT 
            id,
            email,
            password,
            salt
        FROM 
            users 
        WHERE 
            email = ?`;
    var query_params = [emailAddress];

    db.query(
        query, 
        query_params, 
        function(error, result, fields) {
            console.log('No 1')

            if (error) throw error;
            if ( result.length == 1 ) {
                if ( checkPass(password, result[0].password, result[0].salt ) ) {
                    return { id: result[0].id }

                } else {
                    console.log("login False | Password");
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                console.log("login False | username");
                return false;
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Explain your downvote if you can please? I'm happy to add to the question if necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `users.js` function doesn't return anything. The callbacks you're passing `query` do, but the overall function doesn't. Since it never returns anything explicitly, the result of calling it is `undefined`. If you `await` `undefined`, it's like `await Promise.resolve(undefined)` and so your resolution handler is called quite quickly.

You want that function to return a promise that doesn't get resolved until the work is done. Since what it uses is an old-style Node callbck API, it's reasonable to use `new Promise` to create that promise (alternately, get or create a promise-enabled API to that DB).

I also suspect you're calling `connect` incorrectly, since normally that would be an asynchronous action, but you're treating it as though it were synchronous.

See comments:

`users.js`

```
module.exports = function(emailAddress, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Use the callback to know when the connection is established
        db.connect(error => {
            if (error) {
                // Connection failed
                reject(error);
                return;
            }
            var query = `
                SELECT 
                    id,
                    email,
                    password,
                    salt
                FROM 
                    users 
                WHERE 
                    email = ?`;
            var query_params = [emailAddress];
            db.query(
                query, 
                query_params, 
                function(error, result, fields) {
                    // Throwing an error here does nothing useful. Instead,
                    // reject the promise.
                    if (error) {
                        reject(error);
                        return;
                    }
                    // Resolve our promise based on what we got
                    if ( result.length == 1 ) {
                        if ( checkPass(password, result[0].password, result[0].salt ) ) {
                            resolve({ id: result[0].id });
                        } else {
                            console.log("login False | Password");
                            resolve(false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("login False | username");
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Then using it:

```
app.post("/getToken", async function(req, res) {  
    // You must handle errors, since `post` won't do anything with the return
    // value of this function
    try {
        if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
            const email = req.body.email;
            const password = req.body.password;
            // Now this waits here, since `users` returns a promise that
            // isn't resolved until the query completes
            const user = await users(email, password) 
            console.log('No 2')
            if (user) {
                var payload = {
                    id: user.id
                };
                var token = jwt.encode(payload, cfg.jwtSecret);
                res.json({
                    token: token
                });
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(401);
            }
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi T.J. this option seems to only work on the first request, but not the second. based on the error message it appears one of the promises related to the DB connect doesn't resolve itself. `/* This is from db.connect(error => { ... }) error */
(node:29523) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
(node:29523) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: @denden: There are no unhandled promises in the code in the answer, so double-check you've really applied it correctly. But the fact the rejection is unhandled is separate from the other problem, which apparently is that you're not quite using the DB correctly. That's out of scope for the question, but I wouldn't be surprised if you need to connect/disconnect in pairs or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `db.query` function is asynchronous - you are providing callback function that is executed when database call is finished. You probably need to wrap this whole function in Promise:

```
module.exports = function(emailAddress, password) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.connect();
      var query = `
          SELECT 
              id,
              email,
              password,
              salt
          FROM 
              users 
          WHERE 
              email = ?`;
      var query_params = [emailAddress];

      db.query(
          query, 
          query_params, 
          function(error, result, fields) {

              if (error) return reject(error)

              if ( result.length == 1 ) {
                  if ( checkPass(password, result[0].password, result[0].salt ) ) {
                      resolve({id: result[0].id})

                  } else {
                      console.log("login False | Password");
                      reject();
                  }

              } else {
                  console.log("login False | username");
                  reject();
              }
          }
      )
  })
}
```

You can learn more about Promise API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

EDIT:

So you should additionally make `connect` synchronous. Here's a piece of code I have refactored for you. It should work just fine. I have used some ES6 elements to make it more readable.

```
const connect = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.connect((err) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);

      resolve();
    })
  })

const makeDbRequest = (emailAddress, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const query = `
      SELECT 
          id,
          email,
          password,
          salt
      FROM 
          users 
      WHERE 
          email = ?`;

    const query_params = [emailAddress];

    db.query(
        query,
        query_params,
        handleDbData(resolve, reject, password),
    );
  })

const handleDbData = (resolve, reject, password) => (error, result, fields) => {
  if (error) return reject(error)

  if ( result.length == 1 ) {
      if ( checkPass(password, result[0].password, result[0].salt ) ) {
          resolve({id: result[0].id})

      } else {
          console.log("login False | Password");
          reject();
      }

  } else {
      console.log("login False | username");
      reject();
  }
}

module.exports = (emailAddress, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connect()
      .then(() => {
        makeDbRequest(emailAddress, password)
          .then(resolve)
          .catch(reject)
      })
      .catch(reject);
  })
```

Comment: It's true that the OP needs to use a promise in that function, but there are a lot of other things that need fixing as well. (Not least that `db.connect` is presumably also asynchronous, not to mention issues with calling this function from `users.js`.)

Comment: Probably yes. But this is outside of scope of this question. The thing is that he uses async/await on synchronous function that calls asynchronous functions.

Comment: I can't agree that addressing the whole problem is out of scope.

Comment: Yeah. You are probably right. I forgot to synchronize connect as well.

Comment: Thanks, these answers qualify a number of items in my mind, particularly that I was incorrectly treating some items as synchronous.

Comment: @KacperWiszczuk thanks for the additional edit, this is giving an error of `emailAddress` is not defined?

Comment: Forgot to pass emailAddress as a parameter to the function :P